# Input string was not in a correct format MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I just want to convert Session["Price"] to decimal and convert Session["Count"] to integer

```
        doc.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["Price"]);
        doc.Count = Convert.ToInt16(Session["Count"]);
```

I get this error 
[image]

Comment: Clearly whatever value is in `Session["Price"]` can't be directly converted to a decimal.

Comment: What do you think will happen if the Session variable is not defined, or is an empty string or is not a numeric value. Please use your debugger and you will find the reason in no-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stringValue = Session["Price"].ToString();
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) {
    try {
       doc.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(stringValue);
    }
    catch(formatExecption ex) {
        // Should not have gotten here because the frontend should gaurd against input values that are not number but anyway
       throw new ValidationExecption("Price is not a number");
}
```

This issue you have here as a whole is that you are not practicing defensive coding.  Go and learn about defensive coding it will improve the quality of your code